# Undefined index: access_token

Tags: php, office365, access-token, undefined-index

I'm attempting to build a php-based mail app for our school. The school mail service is Office365, and I found the tutorial linked below:

https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/php

After following each step (copying and pasting code) up to Part 5: `Using the Mail API`, I get an authorization code, but apparently no token. What's going on? I'm completely new to this so I have no idea how to fix it.

```
Access Token: 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: access_token in C:\wamp64\www\server\authorize.php on line 10
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  238816  {main}( )   ...\authorize.php:10
```

Comment: Based on the error, it seems that the request for token is failed so that you were not able to get the **accessToken** via the **$tokens** collection. To get the detail error message, I suggest that you using the **Fiddler** to track the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the application ID is also your api token
[image: The photo from the instructions]

Comment: Did that work? If so please let people know by selecting my answer. If you figured it out yourself please answer your own question with however you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem I had to resolve.
Not having an access token is fine, the tutorial is supposed to then get the token using the uri specified.

In oauth.php there is a function

```
public static function getLoginUrl($redirectUri, $scopes) {
```

however in home.php the call is in...

```
<p>Please <a href="<?php echo oAuthService::getLoginUrl($redirectUri)?>">sign in</a> with your Office 365 or Outlook.com account.</p>
```

and this doesn't specify $scopes and as $scopes is defined further up in oauth.php, you can change the function in oauth.php to

```
public static function getLoginUrl($redirectUri){
```

Then when I refreshed the browser and clicked on the sign in link, I got the microsoft login page as I expected.